# Convert a String which is in JSON Format to a JSON Object in java

Tags: java, json

I am currently trying to Automate a API using HTTP client jars. I have stored the response of API which is in JSON format into a Java String object. 
As next step, I would like to convert the response into a JSON Object, which would help me to easily traverse the object. Can you please let me know which API jars or additional libraries I can use to convert the String object into JSON Object.

**apiOutput contains the response which is in the below format.**

```
String apiOutput= {
    "title": "foo",
    "body": "bar",
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 101
}
```

I would like to convert this response into a JSON object to traverse easily.

Comment: If you mean **literally** like in your example, that's not valid java.

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this :

```
import org.json;

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Comment: Which is what is written in one of the linked duplicates.

Comment: While this is correct, this question has been asked countless times on stackoverflow. Answering duplicate questions is not a good idea.

Comment: f1sh all right, I will care in the future

Comment: @TheWildHealer Thank you. Can I use Jackson or gson for this? if yes, how can I do it with them?
I could not find a way as simple as org.json to do with Jackson or GSON.